# Is this example using the stream api in Java 8 the same as a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8, java-stream

Will this code example complete the same task as the for loop below and if so what are the performance differences between using a for loop and the streaming API. If they are the same then why even use a for loop?

**Stream API**

```
currentStatuses.stream().filter(status -> !statuses.contains(status)).forEach(status -> {
    retweetAndFavorite(status);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("tweets.txt")));
    oos.writeObject(currentStatuses);
    oos.close()
});
```

**For Loop**

```
for (Status status : currentStatuses)
{
    if (!statuses.contains(status))
    {
         retweetAndFavorite(status);
         ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("tweets.txt")));
         oos.writeObject(currentStatuses);
         oos.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tested it? As for why `for`, because not everyone is using Java 8. And Java 7 doesn't gain lambdas because Java 8 does. Other reasons might include compatibility and a large existing code base.

Comment: The difference is, one of these two will work. The other won’t compile due to the lack of proper exception handling…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they function the same.

Streams have a slight overhead, when compared to a plain `for` loop, but only on extreme cases will you be able to notice a difference.

One difference is that the stream version is easy to make parallel, if needed, while that requires a fair bit of code without streams.

Streams are usually more concise than `for` loops, often allowing you to complete tasks in a single line of code.

Streams are more [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming), while a `for` loop is [imperative programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming).
It's a matter of style.

It is also a matter of language support. Streams are new in Java 8, so you don't have a choice for older versions. Existing code is rarely converted when upgrading to Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

Your version using `Stream` does not compile. This is because the methods of `ObjectOutputStream` used are declared to throw a checked exception (`IOException` in this case), whereas the method `accept()` of a `Consumer<T>` does not declare any checked exceptions.

In this case you should use a `for` loop.

Apart from this issue with checked exceptions, other reasons for continuing to use `for` loops include:

- Compatibility with earlier versions and existing code,
- Any variable that you use in a lambda that is declared outside must be effectively final, but this restriction does not apply with `for` loops,
- Easier debugging
- Readability. Nested `for` loops in particular don't translate nicely into `Stream`s

Comment: I was actually aware of it not compiling I just didn't include that to stress the point of the stream api vs for loops, but thank you

Comment: Nested loops sometimes can be translated in even more readable way using flatmapping. On the other hand there are more disadvantages on Stream API like harder debugging.

Comment: @TagirValeev Good point about debugging - I've added this to my answer. Personally I don't like using `flatMap` to replace nested `for` loops, but I accept this is just a matter of opinion.